# Missing 'Trackify' App When Looking For 'Lost Submarine' Parts

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm trying to find the missing pieces of the `lost submarine` mini-game.  I couldn't find anything on my map, so I consulted the wiki page and it says I'm supposed to locate them with the Trackify app; it isn't on Michael's phone.  It does, however, show up when I get in the submarine for the `nuclear waste` mini-game.

Why is Trackify not showing up when I'm in the dinghy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parts location are only appearing when the Scuba-diving activity is being triggered, not anytime you're going into the ocean.

The difference between the two is that **you have to get inside of a Dinghy or a Submersible. Then as soon as you exit one of those you'll be equipped with a scuba tank and breathing apparatus.** At this point you'll start to see the closest piece on your map represented by green circles on your map. The Trackify app won't be launched since this one is only used for the nuclear wastes and some specific story-related missions.

Sources: [Submarine Pieces](http://gta.wikia.com/Submarine_Pieces) - [Scuba Diving](http://gta.wikia.com/Scuba_diving)

**Edit:** Oh yeah, and of course you have to buy the Sonar Collections Dock first with Michael ;)

**Edit2:** I think it is still possible to collect the parts without being in "Scuba diving mode" though. You will just see them on your mini-map instead of the full one, this can be useful if you're passing by a part that is not too deep (as for the ones in the city channel) but I would recommend getting the scuba gear for the full run.

**Edit3:** If you're wondering about where to find the vehicle: [Dinghy](http://gta.wikia.com/Dinghy#Locations) - [Submersible](http://gta.wikia.com/Submersible#Locations)

Comment: The app launches when I get into the sub, but that's to track nuclear waste.  Nothing shows up when I drive the dinghy, I didn't notice if anything shows up when I start diving but how would I know where to go?  You definitely can't use the app while diving.

Comment: I just checked a video over Youtube showing how to get the parts (about the map circles I mentionned, but I was a bit wrong). As soon as you started the mission with Abigail and got on the Dinghy, you should see green circles on your map (also visible on Start menu map), these should be the parts you want to collect. Green circle will turn into a blinking one as you get closer.
(As in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6GyuOumJyk)

Comment: I could've sworn it said something about Trackify when I first got on the dinghy, but I can't find anything to back that up.  Anyway, change your answer to reflect the correct info from your comment and I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: Done ! Sorry again for the lack of precision in my first answer. Enjoy the game ;)